Spaces in the object name for astroquery Simbad.query_object
I have a list of object names without any spaces, but the Simbad.query_object of astroquery requires spaces.
For example, with space works... see below:
from astroquery.simbad import Simbad
result_table = Simbad.query_object("W 3 OH")

But without spaces doesn't, see below.
from astroquery.simbad import Simbad
result_table = Simbad.query_object("W3OH")

The warning/error for the second bit is:
WARNING: BlankResponseWarning: Warning: The script line number 3 raised an error (recorded in the `errors` attribute of the result table): 'W3OH' this identifier has an incorrect format for catalog:  W : Westerhout [astroquery.simbad.core]

Is there any way around it? Doing it manually is impossible; the list is quite long!

it depends on the format of the entries. if the pattern is always the same like one_letter one_number two_letters yes it's pretty simple. if not, you can edit your question to include all different patterns

Could you also post a short snippet of your objects text file and what are the objects you are querying from there. You can use string formatting in you entry to split up the objects if the format of the object names is well known.

If you know where the spaces will be (like if you always have objects from the same catalog), I would advise adding the spaces from within python:
from astroquery.simbad import Simbad
list_objects = ["W3OH", "W4OH", "W5OH"]
list_objects_with_spaces = [f"{obj[0]} {obj[1]} {obj[2:]}" for obj in list_objects]
Simbad.query_objects(list_objects_with_spaces)

<Table length=3>
  main_id           ra               dec        coo_err_maj coo_err_min coo_err_angle coo_wavelength coo_bibcode user_specified_id object_number_id
                   deg               deg            mas         mas          deg                                                                   
   object        float64           float64        float32     float32       int16          str1         object         object           int64      
----------- ----------------- ----------------- ----------- ----------- ------------- -------------- ----------- ----------------- ----------------
NAME W 3 OH 36.76708333333334 61.87277777777778          --          --            --                                       W 3 OH                1
                           --                --          --          --            --                                       W 4 OH                2
                           --                --          --          --            --                                       W 5 OH                3


However, if you're not sure where the spaces will be, or how many there are, you can use a wildcard in the query:
from astroquery.simbad import Simbad
list_objects = ["W3OH", "W4OH", "W5OH"]
list_objects_with_wildcard = ["*" + "*".join(obj) for obj in list_objects]
Simbad.query_objects(list_objects_with_wildcard, wildcard=True)

<Table length=8>
        main_id                  ra                 dec         coo_err_maj ... coo_err_angle coo_wavelength     coo_bibcode           matched_id      
                                deg                 deg             mas     ...      deg                                                               
         object               float64             float64         float32   ...     int16          str1             object               object        
------------------------ ------------------ ------------------- ----------- ... ------------- -------------- ------------------- ----------------------
          [W73] OQ 208 H                 --                  --          -- ...            --                                            [W73] OQ 208 H
NAME NGC 7538 IRS 11(OH)  348.4366666666666  61.447222222222216          -- ...            --                1979MNRAS.188..463W [WWW74] NGC 7538(S)-OH
          NAME W75(N)-OH 309.65247232168474   42.62611372777669     10000.0 ...             0              M 2008ApJS..175..277D         NAME W75(N)-OH
      [OWG93] ACO 0465-H  57.71666666666667   6.312222222222222     10000.0 ...            90                1993ApJS...87..135O     [OWG93] ACO 0465-H
                 IC 4255 202.00055491932997 -27.354237874119995      11.032 ...            90              O 2020yCat.1350....0G     [OWG93] ACO 1736-H
           [WMD94] Ori H               92.0                12.0          -- ...            --                                             [WMD94] Ori H
 NAME NGC 7538 IRS 1(OH)  348.4395833333333   61.46944444444445          -- ...            --                1974ApJ...187...41W [WWW74] NGC 7538(N)-OH
             NAME W 3 OH  36.76708333333334   61.87277777777778          -- ...            --                                               NAME W 3 OH

Here we added the * wildcard which can replace any number of any characters at the beginning and between each letter of the object's name.
Queries with wildcards will generally be extremely slow and give you al lot of false positive responses (see above) so they should be last resort if you have no idea of the pattern.
The list of available wildcards can always be displayed with
from astroquery.simbad import Simbad
Simbad.list_wildcards()

*: Any string of characters (including an empty one)
?: Any character (exactly one character)
[abc]: Exactly one character taken in the list. Can also be defined by a range of characters: [A-Z]
[^0-9]: Any (one) character not in the list.

so maybe using ? instead of * could solve the issue of false positives for you here.
Note: always use query_objects over query_object when you're looking for a lot of sources in SIMBAD. If you loop over query_object you'll end up being banned for denial of service attack attempt.
